# Isomorphic React and JSX - rendering component as string on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to render an extremely simple component on the server before passing to the client, transforming using gulp and babelify like so:

```
gulp.task("react-assessment", function(){
  return browserify("./app/assessment/react/components/app.react.js")
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("reactBundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./browser"))
});
```

The component works fine on the client:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");

var Title = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return <h1>Hello World</h1> 
  }
});

module.exports = ReactDOM.render(
  <Title/>, 
  document.getElementById("react-assessment")
);
```

However when I require the file in Node.js with Express, the server crashes with unexpected token

```
return <h1>Hello World</h1> 
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When I've used the old methodology of using `/** @jsx React.DOM */` at the top of the component file, there were no problems.

Route:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");  
    JSX = require('node-jsx').install({
      extension: '.jsx'
    }),
    AssessmentComponent = require("../react/components/app.react.jsx");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you try putting require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'}) at the very top of your require statements?  I believe this module intercepts require calls... so it needs to be first

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used babel/register instead so no need for node-jsx any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using babel/register. No need for React.DOM